# How ad-hoc aliasing of NuGet-referenced assemblies work?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

We had issues in our build with some of our dependencies forcing really old version of a library we were using ourselves at a newer version. This got slightly worse with transitioning towards the new style of project files that no longer explicitly mention DLL resources brought in by NuGet packages, because we lost the ability to mark such assemblies by aliases.

Now, I found out [a solution of basically the same problem](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989) at NuGet's GitHub. I adapted it for our needs in the following way:

```
<Target Name="AliasLog4Net" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'log4net'">
      <Aliases>l4n</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

It works magically. I want to know why though.

- I can't find documentation for `ReferencePath`. Specifically, I would love to know what can I test for in the `Condition` attribute, apart from `%(FileName)`?
- How can I log this logic? Is there a way to write something out for every ad-hoc application of the alias in this way?